# Как убрать границы у элемента Baloon на карте?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите плиз. Я сам верстальщик и JS вообще не знаю. Создал карту и для неё балун. Он имеет белые границы как убрать?

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.988975, 36.231562);
    var myOptions = {
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canva s"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: ""

    });

    var contentString = '<div id="content_map">Тут всё то про что должно быть рассказано</div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: ''
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ВОТ ССЫЛКА ПОСМОТРИТЕ ПЛИЗ
http://jsfiddle.net/RazDva/4a87k/477/

Comment: обсуждая ваш вопрос в чате, один из пользователей ( @Grundy ) посоветовал вам отправиться в справку: `тут скорее RTFM :) надо смотреть какие настройки можно этом балуну выставлять, и наверняка в справке есть пример как кастомизировать его под свои нужды` и ещё: `я говорю - пускай в справку идет :)`